# Is there another version of the Quickbooks Desktop SDK Onscreen reference?

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, qbfc

I have been accessing the OSR via: 
https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

For a while now and that has worked (somewhat - very buggy). It has now stopped working all together and I can no longer proceed without it. Consolibyte wiki is fairly good alternative however it doesnt seem to have the specific country versions nor does it appear to list the different versions like the OSR did.

Does anyone have an alternative for the UK QBXML version 11?

Thanks,

Comment: I already submitted a support ticket to Intuit to get them to fix it.

Comment: Ah, no idea why I didnt think to do that first, thank you. I just assumed they had given up support of the qbXML SDK as it seems in recent months/years they've been moving away from it.

Comment: Okay for future viewers if any. I have been creating a new OSR. Only got the XML side of things done so far and it looks dodgey and right now its on a really slow server but here goes: http://tom.caserta.co.uk/OSR/ I have also put it on github @ https://github.com/Plornt/QuickbooksOSR

Comment: This is bad-ass!!! It's already better than Intuit's!

Comment: Thanks haha, gunna get it properly done in the next week or so. Doesnt work on firefox yet but it should just be a case of including a polyfill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are aware of it. No ETA on when it will be up.  You can use the OSR that comes with the SDK locally. Just run in compatibility mode.